# Android OCR number scanning

Tags: android, ocr

I am developing an android application only for number recognition.

I have found [this](https://github.com/CristianRP/NumerosAndroid) on github.

I tried it and I provided the needed conditions such as light, image clarity that OCR needs to perform well yet the result occasionally shows.

What I want to know is:

- What is wrong in the source code to not obtain the needed result?
- Is there any other solution for this problem?

Comment: So what exactly are the errors you received when it did not work?

Comment: I didn't receive any errors. The app doesn't show any results after scanning.

Comment: As @MoonBloom stated Tesseract and Google Mobile Vision are better alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That project hasn't been touched in 7 months, and the source code is in spanish. I would definitely not use that library. Ever.

You can use Tesseract or Google Mobile Vision to achieve the same, they're much much much much better, and are definitely the 2 leading projects for OCR on Android.

Comment: Do you suggest any existing projects for number scanning? I have found lots of translation projects but they don't meet my needs.

Comment: I quite literally posted the name of 2 projects that can scan numbers and text. You just have to limit them to only scan for numbers. Please actually read what i post.